# Android studio Gradle DSL method not found: compile() while adding slf4android dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0, slf4android

I'm trying to use slf4android dependency from https://github.com/bright/slf4android but having problem with gradle sync.

**Build.gardle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Build.gardle (App)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.vinod.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile('com.gitghub.bright:slf4android:0.1.0'){
            transitive = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile('com.gitghub.bright:slf4android:0.1.0'){
        transitive = true
    }
}

Error that i'm receiving:

```
Error:(26, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:The project 'My Application' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper fileThe build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

I'm very new to android coding and don't know what i'm missing. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

url "http://jitpack.io" is supposed to go in project level build.gradle not in module level.

Change the allProjects of your project level build gradle to this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
}
```

And remove the jitpack url from app build.gradle and sync your project.

Comment: Same error as posted in the question. Tried: moving the url to allprojects in project level build.gradle. removed it from app build.gradle and synced.

Comment: Then your issue is not related to the jitpack library at all. Comment out the repository and dependency and I am sure you will still see the issue.

Comment: Sure issue is not jitpack. As mentioned in the question, issue is with the dependency slf4jandroid. Commenting out the dependency results in synch with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace the Build.Gradle(App) with this and then build :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' 

group='com.github.bright'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 14
    versionName "1.0"
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
androidTestCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-util:1.2.5'

testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
testCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-util:1.2.5'
testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0') {
    exclude module: 'classworlds'
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
    exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
    exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
    exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
    exclude module: 'maven-model'
    exclude module: 'maven-project'
    exclude module: 'maven-settings'
    exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
    exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
    exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
    exclude module: 'wagon-file'
    exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
    exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
}
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Received the following error: Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.